# Unable to use two kendoui dropdowns for one model property in same view

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have tow forms in a view.One for saving address and another is for updating them.
I am using KendoUI dropdown helper for displaying countries and binding the same model for both the forms. In first form dropdown is working fine but in popup form dropdown not working.
[image]
first form

[image]
Popup form

I am using the following way to bind data to dropdown list.
[image]

If i change the name of second dropdown then its rendering correctly but i am unable to receive the selected value in controller as my viewmodel dosent have that name.

Can someone say where i am doing wrong?

Comment: great,some one down vote after two years.. any reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because they are getting the same name/ID.  You can try doing something like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Address.CountryRegionCode)
    .Name("country1")
    ...
)
```

Comment: You are right @mmillican . but my model view doesn't have that field and i was not allowed to create it.Is there any other way to do it

Comment: There's a `[Binding]` attribute that you could probably use in a case like this.  I'll have to look at the syntax later.